# How to watch an imported variable in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ecmascript-2016

I have a file called get.js with an exported function and an exported var within it:

```
var a = false

export function get(url) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = () => {
    a = true // <------------- a has been changed here
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      resolve(xhr.response)
    } else {
      reject(xhr)
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = () => { reject(xhr) }
  xhr.onloadstart =() => {
    a = false // <------------- a has been changed here
  }
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
});
}

export var loadingvar = a;
```

As you can see the value of `a` has been changed twice during the httprequest.

Now I have a Vue file in which I want to watch the value of `a` as follows:

```
import { get, loadingvar } from './get';

export default {
   template: '#calendar',
   name: "Calendar",
   data() {
      return {
        ...
        test: loadingvar,
      }
   },
   watch: {
      test(newVal) {
         console.log(newVal) // This never gets called
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried `"get.loadingvar": function(){}` in watcher but it doesn't work! and Idk where the problem lies.
Thanks for any help here in advance.

Comment: Non-reactive variable cannot be watched. That's a use case for global store that can hold loading state. Even then, loadingvar is an antipattern because there can be simultaneous requests, you need to count requests

Comment: @EstusFlask Correct but shouldn't having the value of `loadingvar` as `$data.test` makes it reactive to vue!?

Comment: @BeHFaR No, because the origin is still non-reactive.

Comment: There is no way how scalar value could be made reactive this way, Vue or not. The only way you can watch it is by polling with setInterval, which is not a proper solution.